# How to include interaction with the command in the same script?

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, scripting, command

I have written a script to run a specific program, my script contains many steps, some of these steps need my simple interaction by writing 0 then enter, How can I do that so that I don't need to interact during the script running ?

for example:

this is part of my script, the third command needs my interaction:

```
    gmx .....        

    gmx mdrun

    gmx trjconv -s md_0_1.tpr -f md_0_1.xtc -o md_noPBC.xtc -pbc mol
```

now the terminal needs an input to continue running the last command:

```
Select group for output
Group     0 (         System) has 189100 elements
Group     1 (          Other) has 189100 elements
Group     2 (            GRM) has 11200 elements
Group     3 (           G8LE) has 177900 elements
Select a group:
```

I need to write "0" and then click enter to finish this command and then my script will run the next command normally.

How can I do that using the same written script ? I have read some posts regarding the expect function but I didn't know how to apply it in my case.

Comment: Does `printf '0\n' | ./script` work?

Comment: Crossposted previously: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1234139/how-to-use-the-script-for-interaction-with-the-written-commands-in-the-same-scri

Comment: @Arkadiusz Drabczyk, No it doesn't work, because the script will not run the next line printf '0\n' | ./script until it finishes the command. at the same time the command will not be finished until I enter 0. It has to be interaction with the command it self

Comment: @steeldriver, yes I know, I have replied to your comment that it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There is sample script **sample.sh**:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Enter parameter
read par
echo Read par $par
```

You can prepare a parameters file `parameters.txt`
0

Then run: `./sample.sh < parameters.txt`

Or you can use like this: `echo 0 | ./sample.sh`

Comment: sorry, I am lost, Can you please describe in details what should I do ? I have my script.sh running now and it will not proceed to the next command or any other command until I write 0 then enter. which means if I added this line in the script  echo 0 | ./sample.sh it will not be read because my terminal is stuck at the last command waiting for me to write 0 and then enter. If I created another scripts (sample.sh) it will not also be read, because my terminal still waiting for my input.

Comment: You can run 'echo 0', right?  It does not ask you to enter anything.  When you do pipe (|), it connects standard output of the first command (echo) with a standard input of another one (sample.sh).  It should not wait for  terminal input.  Something else is going on your system. Which shell are you using?

Comment: I can't run anything because the terminal is waiting my interaction. unless I opened another terminal and do that. May be I didn't understand what you want me to do. I am using bash terminal and I am running my script which contains more than 12 commands  which run a simulation program called gromacs. most of the commands doesn't need interaction, but some of them needs interaction with the program command, so my script doesn't proceed to the next command because it needs my interaction first to finish the present command. please tell me if anything is unclear, I can upload any files if needed

Comment: I think anything I will write should be a part of the present command itself otherwise it will not be read until I manually write enter zero

Comment: Can you type  'echo 0' and press <ENTER>?  It will output 0, right?   Now, when you type 'echo 0 | ./sample.sh <ENTER>' - the second script will reach read command, read from standard input what echo command wrote into the pipe, and you should see output without any interaction.

Comment: echo 0 | gmx trjconv -s md_0_1.tpr -f md_0_1.xtc -o md_noPBC.xtc -pbc mol. Now it works, I wrote echo 0 | before the command line in my script and it worked. could you please modify your answer by writing echo | before my command to accept it as an answer